# SQL query doesnt bring out results when queried using date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I see that a table has the data value as `18-May-2012`. But when I query looking for the same date using the below query, no results are available.

```
Select Submit_Dt From Siebel.S_Order_Dtl
where submit_dt = '18-May-2012'
```

Could you help me sort this issue?

Comment: make sure it is not date column...

Comment: 1 [NLS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch1.htm) formats could be different. 2 it likely has a time component so try `where trunc(Submit_dT) = '18-May-2012'`  trunc will drop the time component on submit_Date.  The engine will then implicitly cast the string to a date thus comparing like components.  This Assumes submit_DT is a date/time while display may only be showing you a date; but storing time.  If this is the case the trunc above should work.  the system will implicitly cast the string date you've entered to a date, provided the NLS format is the Oracle Default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string date into date with TO_DATE() function.
Also you need to take into account that your date might contain hours/minutes/seconds. In order to handle this you need to truncate submit_dt column.

In your case it would look like this:

```
Select Submit_Dt From Siebel.S_Order_Dtl
where TRUNC(submit_dt) = TO_DATE('18-May-2012','dd-MON-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the date to date format using `to_date` as below

```
Select Submit_Dt From Siebel.S_Order_Dtl
where submit_dt = to_date('18-May-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: Or ANSI syntax `DATE '2012-05-18' `